# Nothing Happening On connect method of wifi_iot Flutter package with withInternet flag in Android 11

Tags: android, flutter, android-wifi

I'm trying to connect to wifi with an internet connection in my flutter app using wifi_iot package. The connect method is giving success status but no connection is happening on my device. This is with devices of the above android 10. My target SDK is 29. The devices I tested are the OnePlus 6 with android 11 and Huawei mate 11 lite with android 10.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.